# React JS get current date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to output the current date in my componnent.
In the console my code works, but the React console says:

> bundle.js:14744 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

My component looks like that:

```
import React from 'react';
var FontAwesome = require('react-fontawesome');

export class Date extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        var today = new Date(),
            date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();

        this.state = {
            date: date
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='date'>
                <FontAwesome name='calendar' />{this.state.date}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How should JavaScript know that `new Date()` should refer to the built-in `Date` class and not your `Date` component? FWIW, the issue has nothing to do with React.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your problem is that you are naming your component class `Date`. When you call `new Date()` within your class, it won't create an instance of the `Date` you expect it to create (which is likely [this `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))- it will try to create an instance of your component class. Then the constructor will try to create another instance, and another instance, and another instance... Until you run out of stack space and get the error you're seeing.

If you want to use `Date` within your class, try naming your class something different such as `Calendar` or `DateComponent`.

The reason for this is how JavaScript deals with name scope: Whenever you create a newly named entity if there is already an entity with that name in scope, that name will stop referring to the previous entity and start referring to your new entity. So if you use the name `Date` within a class named `Date`, the name `Date` will refer to that class and not to any object named `Date` which existed before the class definition started.

Answer (score 23):

**OPTION 1**:
if you want to make a common utility function then you can use this

```
export function getCurrentDate(separator=''){

let newDate = new Date()
let date = newDate.getDate();
let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
let year = newDate.getFullYear();

return `${year}${separator}${month<10?`0${month}`:`${month}`}${separator}${date}`
}
```

and use it by just importing it as

```
import {getCurrentDate} from './utils'
console.log(getCurrentDate())
```

**OPTION 2**:
or define and use in a class directly

```
getCurrentDate(separator=''){

let newDate = new Date()
let date = newDate.getDate();
let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
let year = newDate.getFullYear();

return `${year}${separator}${month<10?`0${month}`:`${month}`}${separator}${date}`
}
```

Comment: @StefanBecker How is 3 different Date objects? I only see one `new Date()`. I assume I don't understand something about how the Date object works, so just curious.

Answer (score 22):

**Full date and time :**

```
{new Date().toLocaleString() + ""}
```

**Extract only Month(current):**

```
{new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" })}
```

**Extract only day:**

```
{new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { day : '2-digit'})}
```

**Extract only Year:**

```
{new Date().getFullYear()}
```

Comment: For only Date:
{new Date().toLocaleDateString()}

Answer (score 12):

You can use the react-moment package

-> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment

Put in your file the next line:

```
import moment from "moment";

date_create: moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple Solution would be

```
{new Date().toLocaleString() + ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

my little improvement

```
getCurrentDate(separator=''){

let newDate = new Date()
let date_raw = newDate.getDate();
let month_raw = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
let year = newDate.getFullYear();
var date, month
  
if (date_raw<10)  {  date ="0"+date_raw.toString()} else {  date =date_raw.toString()}
if (month_raw<10)  {  month ="0"+month_raw.toString()} else {  month =month_raw.toString()}


return (
    <div>{year}{separator}{month}{separator}{date}</div>
            );
}
```