# How to add timestamp to firestore onSubmit in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

```
const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(homeEmail === "") {
        alert("Please Provide A Valid E-Mail")
    }
    else {
        db.collection("Home E-Mail").add({
            email: homeEmail
            // I want to add the timestamp at the time of submit
        }).then(() => 
            history.push('/thank-you-junior#thankyou')
        ).catch(() => 
            alert("Oops! Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!")
        )

        setHomeEmail("")
    }
}
```

I have a form which is submitted when `submit` function is called.
How can I add the timestamp to firestore when the submit function is called? I have provided my code and have added the comment where I want to insert timestamp, for the reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React JS get current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744312/react-js-get-current-date)