# How to display current time and date in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Date = () => {
  const date = new Date();

  const n = date.toDateString();

  const time = date.toLocaleTimeString();

  console.log('Date: ' + n);

  console.log('Time: ' + time);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{n}</Text>
      <Text>{time}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Date;
```

I'm getting "undefined is not a constructor ,evaluating new Date()" error and " maximum call state exceeded " error
I want to display date in the format

```
Wed, 20 Jan 2022   9:30 PM
```

How to do this?

Comment: You're declaring `const Date`. Try renaming your component.

Comment: Your component is named `Date` which clashes with the Javascript `Date` object. Try renaming your component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React JS get current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744312/react-js-get-current-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redefined the variable `Date` as the component has the same name. That way, you cannot access the original `Date` anymore. Try renaming your component.